# Powershell binary module - parameter validation

Tags: c#, validation, powershell, data-annotations

I'm learning PowerShell and [one good friend recommended me this beautiful article](http://csharpening.net/?p=738) about binary modules in PowerShell

I'm planning to migrate some of the console applications that I have created to be used as binary modules.

And one of the things that I'd like to do is validate my PowerShell parameters correctly.

I found this post:

http://huddledmasses.org/better-error-messages-for-powershell-validatepattern/

But I'm not sure if this is the approach that I should follow, I mean, I was even planning to use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) to validate my PowerShell parameters in my binary module

In the near future I'm planning to start using more PowerShell directly, but in the meantime, I just want to convert my Console applications to PowerShell binary modules.

Could you guys point me in the right direction?

I just want to know if there is a *more PowerShell way of doing things* in a binary module to vlaidate my parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jaykul's suggestion is more of: how to get new validators for my PowerShell code. Instead, I would start with build-in ones and do extra work only if needed.

You will find a few in System.Management.Automation:

- ValidateArgumentsAttribute
- ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute
- ValidateLengthAttribute
- ValidateRangeAttribute
- ValidatePatternAttribute
- ValidateScriptAttribute
- ValidateCountAttribute
- ValidateSetAttribute
- ValidateNotNullAttribute
- ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute

They are documented on MSDN, eg [ValidateSet docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.validatesetattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I had tried this but for some reason it didn't work out the first time. After I read your response I decided to give it another try and it worked as a charm. Thank you very much man.

Comment: Note also you can write you own by extending [`ValidateArgumentsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.validateargumentsattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.validateenumeratedargumentsattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as applicable.

Comment: How to use ValidateScriptAttribute?